# How to construct a free magma without using identifications/disjoint union?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, magma

> Let $S$ be a set. We define a sequence of sets
>   $(S_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}$ recursively as follows: $S_1=S$ and for
>   $n\ge2$ $$S_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}\{k\}\times\big(S_k\times
>  S_{n-k}\big).$$ Let $M_S=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\{n\}\times S_n$. **We will
>   identify $S_n$ and its canonical image in $M_S$**. For every $w\in M_S$,
>   there exists a unique natural number $n$ such that $w\in S_n$: denote
>   it by $l(w)$.
>
> For $w,w'\in M_S$: let $ww'$ denote the image of $(w,w')$ under the
>   canonical injection of $S_{l(w)}\times S_{l(w')}$ into the sum set
>   $S_{l(w)+l(w')}$.
>
> The set $M_S$ together with the law $(w,w')\mapsto ww'$ is called the
>   free magma constructed on $S$.

How can I revise this construction into one without identifications? Can I just replace "$S_n$" with "$\{n\}\times S_n$" everywhere? But then what happens to the length function $l$? Aren't the $S_n$ and $S_m$ disjoint anyway for $n\ne m$? Why does the construction employ a disjoint union then?

**Edit:**

Is it possible to show that
$$(\forall n)(\forall m)(n\in\mathbb{N}^*\land m\in\mathbb{N}^*\land m\ne n\Rightarrow S_n\cap S_m=\emptyset)?$$
Would I need to induct on $n,m$?

Comment: It seems the $\{k\}$ and $\{n\}$ are just here to ensure that no funny business happens with the sets and that all unions are really disjoint. It's more or less aesthetics at this point, in my opinion.

Comment: When you want to add to [your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3622497/29335) don't just repost. Use the edit button. I closed the other one as a duplicate of this one.